# Inicializar apache e mysql no windows 7 32 Bits utilizando o Xampp

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

Gostaria de inicializar o Apache e Mysql do Xampp assim que o sistema for inicializado, dei umas pesquisadas e achei isso:

> Instalação do serviço: No C:/xampp/apache duplo-clique em "apache_installservice.bat".
>   Desinstalação do serviço: No C:/xampp/apache duplo-clique em "apache_uninstallservice.bat"
>
> Instalação do serviço: No C:/xampp/mysql duplo-clique em "mysql_installservice.bat". Desinstalação do serviço: No 
>   C:/xampp/mysql duplo-clique em "mysql_uninstallservice.bat"

Mas me deparei com o seguinte problema, quando executo ambos aparecem as seguintes mensagens a seguir, respectivamente:

> Installing Apache2.4 as an Service
>   **Installing the 'Apache2.4' service
>   (OS 5)Acesso negado.  : AH00369: Failed to open the Windows service manager, per
>   haps you forgot to log in as Adminstrator?
>   Now we Start Apache2.4 :)
>   O nome de serviço é inválido.**
>
> Para obter mais ajuda, digite NET HELPMSG 2185.
>
> Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
>
> ---
>
> Installing MySQL as an Service
>   **O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. Install/Remove of
>   the Service Denied! Try to start the MySQL deamon as service ... O
>   nome de serviço é inválido.**
>
> Para obter mais ajuda, digite NET HELPMSG 2185.
>
> Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .

Alguém poderia ajudar, agradeço!

Comment: Execute o `apache_installservice.bat` e `mysql_installservice.bat` como **Administrador** clicando o botão direito do mouse.

Comment: Você qr inicializar o apache e o mysql junto com o windows, é isso?

Comment: Sim @gato, quando o sistema iniciar ele já inicie, o apache e o mysql.

Comment: @LaércioLopes, Executando como Administador...  Installing MySQL as an Service
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
Install/Remove of the Service Denied!
Try to start the MySQL deamon as service ...
O nome de serviço é inválido.

Para obter mais ajuda, digite NET HELPMSG 2185.

Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .

Comment: Vai no **Painel de Controle**, **Contas de Usuário**, **Alterar configurações de Controle de Conta de Usuário** e abaixa o botão todo, reinicia o computador e tente novamente.

Comment: Okay, deu certo! Obrigado!

Comment: Vou colocar como resposta e você aceita ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto está acontecendo porque você está tentando executar esses arquivos `.bat`sem os privilégios de uma conta de **Administrador** ou o Controle de Conta de Usuário está habilitado.

Para desabilitar o controle de conta vá em:

> **Painel de Controle, Contas de Usuário, Alterar configurações de
>   Controle de Conta de Usuário**, abaixa o botão todo, reinicia o
>   computador e quando o Windows iniciar novamente tente executar os arquivos
>   `.bat`.

Answer (score 3):

Esta [solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20960324/5429980) funciona para mim.

Abra o XAMPP Control Painel, e clique no botão **config**. Veja:

[image: xampp config]

em seguida basta você habilitar o Autostart correspondente ao Mysql e o Apache e clicar no botão **Save**. Veja abaixo:

[image: autostart]

Mas, é necessário iniciar o XAMPP junto com o Windows, para fazer isso basta colar o caminho do atalho do XAMPP para esta pasta:

> C:\Users\ USERNAME \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

ou

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

No meu PC o caminho da pasta de inicialização do Windows é este:

> C:\Users\Gato\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup